# Unable to edit AppManifest.xml?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on my N64 emulator for android, I have been thrown a ton of errors, So I find out that the error is originating from my app manifest. So I go to edit it and I get thrown this error:

`Plug-in com.android.ide.eclipse.adt was unable to load class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.manifest.ManifestEditor.`

Has anybody else gotten this, Also I have gotten alot of other errors of the same manor like the hyper link finder and stuff like that.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my own problem, If any of you are experiencing this problem, Just try restarting eclipse. I don't know how I fixed it but it just is.